# Mathematical Operations on Django Annotations

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates

I have a Django model that defines a TimeSlot. Each TimeSlot can hold a certain number of users (`TimeSlot.spots`). Each TimeSlot also has a certain number of users already held in it (a many to many field, `TimeSlot.participants`.

When I pass to the template that displays the available TimeSlots to the user, I annotate with `TimeSlot.objects.annotate(Count('participants'))`,which gives the number of users currently held by the TimeSlot as `participants__count`.

However, what I really want is the number of spots remaining, the capacity (`TimeSlot.spots`) minus the number currently held (`participants__count`). How can I annotate another field with this new number, so I can pass it to the template?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Subtracting two annotated columns](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17374467/subtracting-two-annotated-columns)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not possible with only an annotation. I'd create a method on the model which does the annotation, and then subtract that from your `TimeSlot.spots` value. This will use more database queries, but thats your only option. Or I guess you could drop down to raw SQL...

Comment: Thanks, I was worried that might be the case. I think that what I'll end up doing is set up the ManyToManyManager on the `TimeSlot.participants` so that whenever it adds a person it decrements `TimeSlot.spots,` which is a little less elegant but definetly cheaper in the long run.

Answer (score 3):

It's still not possible with annotation (though it is planned to implement in Django). But you can do it with an `.extra()` query. See my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26602086/2151195) to another question for details.

Upd.:

Essentially, you need somethig like this query:

```
items = MyModel.objects.extra(
    select = {'variance': 'Model.someField - SUM(relatedModel__someField)'},
)
```