# How to subtract two annotated columns on Django QuerySets?

Tags: python, django, django-queryset, django-orm, django-annotate

I need to be able to sort on the aggregate of two annotated columns

So I'd like to do something like this:

```
c = c.annotate(metric=Sum('results__metric'))
c = c.annotate(metric_prior=Sum('results__metric_prior'))
c = c.annotate(variance=F('metric')-F('metric_prior')) #doesn't work, for demonstrative purposes only
```

and then:

```
c = c.order_by('variance')
```

Does anyone know how to accomplish something like the above?

Comment: I believe the Django ORM can't be bent so much, but I'm upvoting your question because I would like to see if anyone can stretch it so far. My advice is to either get your hands dirty using with raw SQL or use a more powerful ORM like SQLAlchemy (you can use it along with the Django ORM, see SQLSoup).

Comment: this feature is close to making it into a future version of Django https://github.com/django/django/pull/2496

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Actually,

```
c = c.annotate(variance=F('metric')-F('metric_prior'))
```

[works as you would like it to](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/expressions/#using-f-with-annotations) [starting with Django 1.8](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/releases/1.8/#query-expressions-conditional-expressions-and-database-functions).

Moreover, you can also order by an expression, which means you can just use:

```
c = c.order_by(F('metric') - F('metric_prior'))
```

or even just:

```
c = c.order_by(Sum('results__metric') - Sum('results__metric_prior'))
```

Answer (score 1):

[Ticket](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/14030) is there for more than 4 years (by 2014), but it can be accomplished with a little `.extra()` query, like this:

```
items = MyModel.objects.extra(
    select = {'variance': 'SUM(relatedModel__someField) - SUM(relatedModel__someField)'},
)
```

Yes, it can be a bit unpredictable with different DBMS. But if you limit the syntax inside extra to very common SQL it should work more or less everywhere.