# Complex django queryset annotation with multiple subqueries

Tags: django, django-orm

Here is some annotation list:

```
    count_set = {
        'num_followers': 'following_followinguser_leader',
        'num_followings': 'following_followinguser_follower',
    }

    for k, v in count_set.iteritems():
        qs = qs.annotate(**{k: models.Count(v, distinct=True)})
    return qs
```

I'm looking for solution of adding `all` field which will be a number of unique elements in `num_followers` and `num_followings`.

Problem is that is should be fast enough, the best way is pure SQL, but what about django ORM?

**UPD:** PostgreSQL table schema for following

```
            Table "public.following_followinguser"
     Column      |           Type           |  Modifiers                               
-----------------+--------------------------+------------------------------
id               | integer                  | not null
follower_id      | integer                  | not null
leader_id        | integer                  | not null
```

Where follower and leader ids are links to custom user model inherited from `AbstractUser`. `following_followinguser_leader` is related name for leader field of model above.

**e.g.** Let followers will be users with ids: 1, 2, 3 and user 4 is follower for users with ids 1, 5, 6. Than all should be: 1, 2, 3, 5, 6. All I need is number of that, i.e. 5.

Answer (score 1):

The SQL generated will probably be as tight as you can make it via the Django ORM.  You can always validate that by printing out qs.query.sql_with_params() and seeing the generated SQL.  If you need to, you can add indexes to the columns to speed up the count (postgres 9.2+).

Comment: Then I must misunderstand your models.  Can you add them to your question?

Comment: I understand now.  Your models have db_column for each of the fields.  I'll edit my answer.

Comment: Well I need ``TOTAL`` to be equal to number of elements in total set ```TOTAL = |FOLLOWERS + FOLLOWINGS|```

Comment: Then I think you want the same answer as [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17374467/subtracting-two-annotated-columns) SO question.  Only way I see it being done is iterating over the queryset and doing it by hand, or raw SQL.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63709/discussion-between-outoftime-and-beltiras).